# Send accurate ERC 20 custom token

Tags: web3js, ether, erc-20

I have one issue, I can't send accurate custom ERC 20 token to an ether address.

Here is my custom token detail.

[Balance](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0xb74f749bc6954c2703773a4c1a9ba49bf754db77?a=0x1ACC69A05E1374ec008c998d7D8038465Ee73C7b):   0.000000000000000324 BucksTec

Decimals:   18

I sent 44 tokens to an ether address but it shows 0.000000000000000068 [Tokens Transfered](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x5e52fb2f2343bd913b75741db1f3f02a12465854f3b37d7a50b5a5055a1244b0).

My question is how can I send accurately tokens, please need your best advice and experience.

Some code:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('https://ropsten.infura.io/xyz'));

module.exports.sendTokensTest = function(req, res){

    var toAddress = req.body.toAddress;
    var coins  = req.body.quantity;
    coins = "0x"+coins;
    var fromAddress  = req.body.fromAddress;
    var privateKey  = req.body.fromAddressPvtKey;

    try{

        var contractAddress = contractConfigTest.contractAddress;
        var contractAbi = contractConfigTest.abiArray;

        //res.send({contractAddress:contractAddress, contractAbi:contractAbi});

        var myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractAbi, contractAddress);

        myContract.options.from = fromAddress;

        var transactionObject = {
            from: fromAddress,
            to: contractAddress,
            value: '0x00', 
            data: myContract.methods.transfer(toAddress, coins).encodeABI(),
            chainId: 3
        };

        web3.eth.estimateGas(transactionObject, function(err1, estimateGas){
            transactionObject.gasLimit = estimateGas;

            if(err1){
                res.send({error:true, errorMsg:err1.message, errorFunction:'estimateGas' });
            }

            web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(transactionObject, privateKey , function(err2, signed){

                if(err2){
                    res.send({error:true, errorMsg:err2.message, errorFunction:'signTransaction'});
                }

                web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction, function(err3, txHash){

                    if(err3){
                        res.send({error:true, errorMsg:err3.message, errorFunction:'sendSignedTransaction'});
                    }

                    res.send({txHash:txHash});
                });

            });

        });

    }catch(err){
        res.send({error:true, errorMsg:err.message, errorFunction:'sendTokens' });
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0x44` is 68 in decimals. Moreover, your token has 18 decimals. This means that to send one unit of a token, you need to send `1 * 10^18`. Remember, there are no decimals on ethereum, and everything is handled in the lowest possible units.

Try sending `1000000000000000000` units (no `0x` before it, that will convert it to base 16, you want to convert the number to base 16 directly, not just prepend `0x`) to send `1 token`.

Comment: thanks, so if I want to send 44 tokens then I need to multiply something like this `(44 * 100000000000000000) = 4400000000000000000;` ?

Comment: Yes, you would need to multiply by `n * 10^decimals`

Comment: When I sent 4 coins then it works but when I tried to send 10 coins it display me this error `Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number "1.0E 19" to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "1.0E 19"`
echo  (10 * pow(10, 18)); // 1.0E+19

Comment: Use a bignum lib for JS

Comment: do you konw how to convert `1.0E+19` into integer, I'm using php `echo (10 * pow(10, 18)); // 1.0E+19 `

Comment: You will need to use whatever Bignum libraries PHP has, ethereum numbers can often exceed the datatype limits on most languages

Comment: Hi, I want to clear one more point on how to display tokens in decimal form like `516.000000000000000344` this is displaying at ropsten but when I show these token in my web page they display `516000000000000000344` , no decimal here.

Comment: You do the reverse, divide by `10^decimals`

Comment: I already did that and it is working now. I really appreciate your response how good are you (Y). Thanks.